# Unrecognized opcode on floating-point Assembly instructions for Xiao ESP32-C3 (RISC-V based)

Tags: assembly, esp32, arduino-ide, riscv

I'm trying to implement [Ivan Kostoski's](https://github.com/ikostoski/esp32-i2s-slm) code for an ESP32-based sound level meter on a Seeed Xiao ESP32-C3.

According to the Seeed's [wiki](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/XIAO_ESP32C3_Getting_Started/), that chip “is a 32-bit RISC-V CPU, which includes an FPU (Floating Point Unit) for 32-bit single-precision arithmetic”. So, based on this I wrote some RISC-V Assembly code for floating point operations. however, when I try to compile I get the error `unrecognized opcode` on every floating point instruction. Other instructions don't throw errors.

Here's the Arduino IDE console output. Notice how the first instruction (`addi`) doesn't throw an error.

```
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s: Assembler messages:
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:12: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f0,0(a5)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:13: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f1,4(a5)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:14: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f2,8(a5)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:15: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f3,12(a5)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:16: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f4,0(a6)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:17: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f5,4(a6)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:22: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f6,a2'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:24: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmadd.s f6,f2,f4'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:25: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmadd.s f6,f3,f5'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:26: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmv.s f7,f6'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:27: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmadd.s f7,f0,f4'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:28: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmadd.s f7,f1,f5'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:29: Error: unrecognized opcode `fsw f7,a3'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:31: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmv.s f5,f4'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:32: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmv.s f4,f6'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:34: Error: backward ref to unknown label "1:"
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:37: Error: unrecognized opcode `fsw f4,0(a6)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:38: Error: unrecognized opcode `fsw f5,4(a6)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:39: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmvi a2,0'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:48: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f0,0(a5)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:49: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f1,4(a5)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:50: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f2,8(a5)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:51: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f3,12(a5)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:52: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f4,0(a6)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:53: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f5,4(a6)'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:54: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmv.s f6,a7'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:55: Error: unrecognized opcode `fli f10,0.0'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:56: Error: symbol `loop' is already defined
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:59: Error: symbol `i' is already defined
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:60: Error: unrecognized opcode `flw f7,a2'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:62: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmadd.s f7,f2,f4'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:63: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmadd.s f7,f3,f5'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:64: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmv.s f8,f7'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:65: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmadd.s f8,f0,f4'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:66: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmadd.s f8,f1,f5'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:67: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmul.s f9,f8,f6'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:68: Error: unrecognized opcode `fsw f9,a3'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:70: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmv.s f5,f4'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:71: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmv.s f4,f7'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:72: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmadd.s f10,f9,f9'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:74: Error: backward ref to unknown label "1:"
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:76: Error: symbol `exit' is already defined
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:77: Error: unrecognized opcode `fsw f4,a6,0'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:78: Error: unrecognized opcode `fsw f5,a6,4'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s:79: Error: unrecognized opcode `fmr a2,f10'
C:\...\cc4DgX57.s: Error: local label `"1" (instance number 1 of a fb label)' is not defined
```

This is the reference code, written in the Xtensa ISA, that I'm trying to port to RISC-V:

```
extern "C" {
  int sos_filter_f32(float *input, float *output, int len, const SOS_Coefficients &coeffs, SOS_Delay_State &w);
} 
__asm__ (
  //
  // ESP32 implementation of IIR Second-Order Section filter 
  // Assumes a0 and b0 coefficients are one (1.0)
  //
  // float* a2 = input;
  // float* a3 = output;
  // int    a4 = len;
  // float* a5 = coeffs;
  // float* a6 = w; 
  // float  a7 = gain;
  //
  ".text                    \n"
  ".align  4                \n"
  ".global sos_filter_f32   \n"
  ".type   sos_filter_f32,@function\n"
  "sos_filter_f32:          \n"
  "  entry   a1, 16         \n"
  "  lsi     f0, a5, 0      \n" // float f0 = coeffs.b1;
  "  lsi     f1, a5, 4      \n" // float f1 = coeffs.b2;
  "  lsi     f2, a5, 8      \n" // float f2 = coeffs.a1;
  "  lsi     f3, a5, 12     \n" // float f3 = coeffs.a2;
  "  lsi     f4, a6, 0      \n" // float f4 = w[0];
  "  lsi     f5, a6, 4      \n" // float f5 = w[1];
  "  loopnez a4, 1f         \n" // for (; len>0; len--) { 
  "    lsip    f6, a2, 4    \n" //   float f6 = *input++;
  "    madd.s  f6, f2, f4   \n" //   f6 += f2 * f4; // coeffs.a1 * w0
  "    madd.s  f6, f3, f5   \n" //   f6 += f3 * f5; // coeffs.a2 * w1
  "    mov.s   f7, f6       \n" //   f7 = f6; // b0 assumed 1.0
  "    madd.s  f7, f0, f4   \n" //   f7 += f0 * f4; // coeffs.b1 * w0
  "    madd.s  f7, f1, f5   \n" //   f7 += f1 * f5; // coeffs.b2 * w1 -> result
  "    ssip    f7, a3, 4    \n" //   *output++ = f7;
  "    mov.s   f5, f4       \n" //   f5 = f4; // w1 = w0
  "    mov.s   f4, f6       \n" //   f4 = f6; // w0 = f6
  "  1:                     \n" // }
  "  ssi     f4, a6, 0      \n" // w[0] = f4;
  "  ssi     f5, a6, 4      \n" // w[1] = f5;
  "  movi.n   a2, 0         \n" // return 0;
  "  retw.n                 \n"
);

extern "C" {
  float sos_filter_sum_sqr_f32(float *input, float *output, int len, const SOS_Coefficients &coeffs, SOS_Delay_State &w, float gain);
}
__asm__ (
  //
  // ESP32 implementation of IIR Second-Order section filter with applied gain.
  // Assumes a0 and b0 coefficients are one (1.0)
  // Returns sum of squares of filtered samples
  //
  // float* a2 = input;
  // float* a3 = output;
  // int    a4 = len;
  // float* a5 = coeffs;
  // float* a6 = w;
  // float  a7 = gain;
  //
  ".text                    \n"
  ".align  4                \n"
  ".global sos_filter_sum_sqr_f32 \n"
  ".type   sos_filter_sum_sqr_f32,@function \n"
  "sos_filter_sum_sqr_f32:  \n"
  "  entry   a1, 16         \n" 
  "  lsi     f0, a5, 0      \n"  // float f0 = coeffs.b1;
  "  lsi     f1, a5, 4      \n"  // float f1 = coeffs.b2;
  "  lsi     f2, a5, 8      \n"  // float f2 = coeffs.a1;
  "  lsi     f3, a5, 12     \n"  // float f3 = coeffs.a2;
  "  lsi     f4, a6, 0      \n"  // float f4 = w[0];
  "  lsi     f5, a6, 4      \n"  // float f5 = w[1];
  "  wfr     f6, a7         \n"  // float f6 = gain;
  "  const.s f10, 0         \n"  // float sum_sqr = 0;
  "  loopnez a4, 1f         \n"  // for (; len>0; len--) {
  "    lsip    f7, a2, 4    \n"  //   float f7 = *input++;
  "    madd.s  f7, f2, f4   \n"  //   f7 += f2 * f4; // coeffs.a1 * w0
  "    madd.s  f7, f3, f5   \n"  //   f7 += f3 * f5; // coeffs.a2 * w1;
  "    mov.s   f8, f7       \n"  //   f8 = f7; // b0 assumed 1.0
  "    madd.s  f8, f0, f4   \n"  //   f8 += f0 * f4; // coeffs.b1 * w0;
  "    madd.s  f8, f1, f5   \n"  //   f8 += f1 * f5; // coeffs.b2 * w1; 
  "    mul.s   f9, f8, f6   \n"  //   f9 = f8 * f6;  // f8 * gain -> result
  "    ssip    f9, a3, 4    \n"  //   *output++ = f9;
  "    mov.s   f5, f4       \n"  //   f5 = f4; // w1 = w0
  "    mov.s   f4, f7       \n"  //   f4 = f7; // w0 = f7;
  "    madd.s  f10, f9, f9  \n"  //   f10 += f9 * f9; // sum_sqr += f9 * f9;
  "  1:                     \n"  // }
  "  ssi     f4, a6, 0      \n"  // w[0] = f4;
  "  ssi     f5, a6, 4      \n"  // w[1] = f5;
  "  rfr     a2, f10        \n"  // return sum_sqr; 
  "  retw.n                 \n"  // 
);
```

And here's my RISC-V code:

```
extern "C" {
  int sos_filter_f32(float *input, float *output, int len, const SOS_Coefficients &coeffs, SOS_Delay_State &w);
} 
__asm__ (
  //
  // RISC-V implementation of IIR Second-Order Section filter 
  // Assumes a0 and b0 coefficients are one (1.0)
  //
  // float* a2 = input;
  // float* a3 = output;
  // int    a4 = len;
  // float* a5 = coeffs;
  // float* a6 = w; 
  // float  a7 = gain;
  //
  ".text                    \n"
  ".p2align  2              \n"
  ".globl sos_filter_f32    \n"
  ".type   sos_filter_f32,@function\n"
  "sos_filter_f32:          \n"
  "  addi sp, sp, -16       \n"
  "  flw     f0, 0(a5)      \n" // float f0 = coeffs.b1;
  "  flw     f1, 4(a5)      \n" // float f1 = coeffs.b2;
  "  flw     f2, 8(a5)      \n" // float f2 = coeffs.a1;
  "  flw     f3, 12(a5)     \n" // float f3 = coeffs.a2;
  "  flw     f4, 0(a6)      \n" // float f4 = w[0];
  "  flw     f5, 4(a6)      \n" // float f5 = w[1];
  "  loop:                  \n"
  "    bnez    a4, 1f       \n" // for (; len>0; len--) { 
  "    j exit               \n"
  "  i:                     \n"
  "    flw     f6, a2       \n" //   float f6 = *input++;
  "    addi    a2, a2, 4    \n" //   post-increment by 4
  "    fmadd.s f6, f2, f4   \n" //   f6 += f2 * f4; // coeffs.a1 * w0
  "    fmadd.s f6, f3, f5   \n" //   f6 += f3 * f5; // coeffs.a2 * w1
  "    fmv.s   f7, f6       \n" //   f7 = f6; // b0 assumed 1.0
  "    fmadd.s f7, f0, f4   \n" //   f7 += f0 * f4; // coeffs.b1 * w0
  "    fmadd.s f7, f1, f5   \n" //   f7 += f1 * f5; // coeffs.b2 * w1 -> result
  "    fsw     f7, a3       \n" //   *output++ = f7;
  "    addi    a3, a3, 4    \n" //   post-increment by 4
  "    fmv.s   f5, f4       \n" //   f5 = f4; // w1 = w0
  "    fmv.s   f4, f6       \n" //   f4 = f6; // w0 = f6
  "    addi    a4, a4, -1   \n" //   update loop counter
  "    bnez    a4, 1b       \n"
  "    j exit               \n"
  "  exit:                  \n" // }
  "  fsw     f4, 0(a6)      \n" // w[0] = f4;
  "  fsw     f5, 4(a6)      \n" // w[1] = f5;
  "  fmvi    a2, 0          \n" // return 0;
  "  ret                    \n"
);

extern "C" {
  float sos_filter_sum_sqr_f32(float *input, float *output, int len, const SOS_Coefficients &coeffs, SOS_Delay_State &w, float gain);
}
__asm__ (
  //
  // RISC-V implementation of IIR Second-Order section filter with applied gain.
  // Assumes a0 and b0 coefficients are one (1.0)
  // Returns sum of squares of filtered samples
  //
  // float* a2 = input;
  // float* a3 = output;
  // int    a4 = len;
  // float* a5 = coeffs;
  // float* a6 = w;
  // float  a7 = gain;
  //
  ".text                    \n"
  ".p2align  2              \n"
  ".globl sos_filter_sum_sqr_f32 \n"
  ".type   sos_filter_sum_sqr_f32,@function \n"
  "sos_filter_sum_sqr_f32:  \n"
  "  addi sp, sp, -16       \n"
  "  flw     f0, 0(a5)      \n" // float f0 = coeffs.b1;
  "  flw     f1, 4(a5)      \n" // float f1 = coeffs.b2;
  "  flw     f2, 8(a5)      \n" // float f2 = coeffs.a1;
  "  flw     f3, 12(a5)     \n" // float f3 = coeffs.a2;
  "  flw     f4, 0(a6)      \n" // float f4 = w[0];
  "  flw     f5, 4(a6)      \n" // float f5 = w[1];
  "  fmv.s   f6, a7         \n" // float f6 = gain;
  "  fli     f10, 0.0       \n" // float sum_sqr = 0;
  "  loop:                  \n"
  "    bnez    a4, 1f       \n" // for (; len>0; len--) {
  "    j exit               \n"
  "  i:                     \n"
  "    flw     f7, a2       \n" //   float f7 = *input++;
  "    addi    a2, a2, 4    \n" //   post-increment by 4
  "    fmadd.s f7, f2, f4   \n" //   f7 += f2 * f4; // coeffs.a1 * w0
  "    fmadd.s f7, f3, f5   \n" //   f7 += f3 * f5; // coeffs.a2 * w1;
  "    fmv.s   f8, f7       \n" //   f8 = f7; // b0 assumed 1.0
  "    fmadd.s f8, f0, f4   \n" //   f8 += f0 * f4; // coeffs.b1 * w0;
  "    fmadd.s f8, f1, f5   \n" //   f8 += f1 * f5; // coeffs.b2 * w1; 
  "    fmul.s  f9, f8, f6   \n" //   f9 = f8 * f6;  // f8 * gain -> result
  "    fsw     f9, a3       \n" //   *output++ = f9;
  "    addi    a3, a3, 4    \n" //   post-increment by 4
  "    fmv.s   f5, f4       \n" //   f5 = f4; // w1 = w0
  "    fmv.s   f4, f7       \n" //   f4 = f7; // w0 = f7;
  "    fmadd.s f10, f9, f9  \n" //   f10 += f9 * f9; // sum_sqr += f9 * f9;
  "    addi    a4, a4, -1   \n" //   update loop counter
  "    bnez    a4, 1b       \n"
  "    j exit               \n"
  "  exit:                  \n" // }
  "  fsw     f4, a6, 0      \n" // w[0] = f4;
  "  fsw     f5, a6, 4      \n" // w[1] = f5;
  "  fmr     a2, f10        \n" // return sum_sqr; 
  "  ret                    \n" // 
);
```

I'm using single-precision instructions that, according to the manufacturer, should be supported. Still, the `unrecognized opcode` error suggests otherwise.

I have the board correctly installed on the Arduino IDE, and I've selected it before compiling, so it's not that the code is being compiled for an unrelated RISC-V chip without floating point support.

The rest of my code is not the issue, since I've ported the above functions to C++ (following Ivan's comments on the Assembly code) and they do compile and work.

Comment: Have you tried compiling a function like `float foo(float *p){ return *p; }` and looking at the asm to make sure your IDE really is compiling for RISC-V with FPU support enabled?   https://godbolt.org/z/51df19P4z shows GCC targeting RV32gc uses `flw fa0,0(a0)`, so it is using the `flw` instruction mnemonic.  (I assume `fa0` vs. `f0` is just the FP version of ABI names like `a0` vs. register numbers like `x10`.)

Comment: @ajs00 - posted an answer explaining why this isn't working. But I also wanted to wish you good luck, I've also worked with that sound level code but have stayed with the original ESP32s that it has assembly for because of the pain in rewriting the code for other models. Other than that it's definitely a very nice piece of software.

Comment: I looked into the Arduino IDE console output to see if I could disassemble the code but that would take longer than its worth. I did see the `RISCV32IMC` parameter being passed to the compiler, so that should prove that floating-point operations are just not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeed Studio is not the manufacturer. They sell dev boards which use the ESP32-C3 (among other CPUs) but they don't manufacture the ESP32-C3. Espressif does, and the key thing is to look at [Espressif's Technical Reference](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c3_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf) document for the CPU, not Seeed Studio's sales information.

Datasheets rarely call out what's *not* supported, so the technical reference never plainly states "floating point extensions not supported". There are many versions of RISC V CPUs; Espressif describes the CPU used in the C3 as supporting "base integer (I), multiplication/division (M) and compressed (C) standard extensions" (1.1 ESP ­RISC­ V CPU Overview).

Later in the document it show that the indicates that single, double and quad precision floating-point extensions are all unavailable (flags in the `misa` - Machine ISA - register).

The instructions you're trying to use - `fmadd.s`, `fmv.s`, etc - are all part of the [floating computational instructions](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/riscv-spec-20191213.pdf) which the `misa` register indicates aren't supported, which is why the code you wrote doesn't build.

Comparing the ESP32-C3 to other ESP32 CPUs, you can look at it as the "value processor" of the line. Espressif's current RISC-V CPUs have less internal memory, are single core, don't support PSRAM, and don't have the single, double or quadruple RISC-V floating point computational extensions. Espressif's other CPUs (the original ESP32, ESP32-S2 and ESP32-S3) are all more capable in varying ways, and all cost more.

My best suggestion for an alternative for you is to do what @Peter Cordes suggested in a comment; inspect the assembly code output of the compiler and base your code on what you find there.

Comment: Update: I managed to disassemble the code, and surely there are no floating-point instructions.

Here's an excerpt: https://www.paste.org/126427